# Recover SO account after google mail has been closed

Tags: account

True story bros, can't post on meta because I don't have enough rep here.  So I ask here, prepared for the flames (of love).

I had a google account that was provided through my college which I have graduated and moved on.  The account has been closed and now it appears I can not log into my SO account anymore that was associated with that google account.

Do I have any options to recover it or do I start over and lose my (not so) massive amounts of rep, badges, and the access to my previous Qs and As.

Thanks for the certain kind responses I am sure to get for this question.

Comment: You might want to use the ["Contact Us" link](http://stackoverflow.com/contact). Also, I suspect you had a Google Apps account, since a college should not have anything to do with your Google account? Also, be prepared to lose the account, since I can't think of a way to prove to the admins that you are the same person who that account belonged to - I hope I am wrong, good luck. That said, I'll vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you.  I must have miseed the contact us.. what a noob.

Comment: Nah, it was an email account.  With a school domain ending, but powered by gmail.  I could do all the google account stuff with it (sign into youtube, here, etc..)  Anyway, sent a help request, we'll see.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like [Google Apps account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/72709?hl=en). They're almost the same but not quite.

Comment: HAHAHAHA Victory.  Somehow my home computer could auto login.. I only tried from laptop and work comp, Some how, even though I couldn't log into my email.  Can certainly close this because I've added logins now. 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, you just find a computer that you have set to log into automatically to your e-mail and haven't since logged out since the expiration of your account.  Then the credentials should still be valid for SO.

Once you are logged in here, then you just follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) and you can add more login credentials to your SO account.